# Port recordings from old versions of CSS to newer version

Tags: counter-strike-source, recording

How does one port old recordings to recently patched versions of CSS?  (Counter strike source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [discussions](http://www.gotfrag.com/css/forums/thread/279489/) on how to do this, but they are from 2007 with a very old version of CS:S.  The [general consensus](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1329987) on the official forums is that it's not possible.